# Setting a ToggleButton Variable in the behind code in silverlight

Tags: silverlight

Here is what i am trying to do

```
private ToggleButton _itemChecked=Name_Of_Element_In_Xaml;
```

That doesnt work. Is there a way?

Comment: What error are you getting?  Can you post the relevant bit of the XAML?  Is the element named in your UserControl, or in a template (e.g. in your resources section)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it.

```
private ToggleButton _itemChecked=FindName("Name_Of_Element_In_Xaml");
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to create it in the code behind if you already named it in xaml.

If you do this in xaml:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <ToggleButton x:Name="myToggleButton"></ToggleButton>
</Grid>
```

You can do this in code behind:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    myToggleButton.Content = "Toggle Me";
}
```

Cheers, Phil